# Formerly Dead Dwellers Misbehaving (ungrateful peasants!)

Tags: fallout-shelter

The entire lower third of my vault is normally unoccupied and full of production rooms that exist solely to increase my power/food/water storage. Unfortunately, incidents do happen down there, so I send dwellers down there occasionally to squash roaches and choke Molerats to death with their delicious meats. Invariably, because of the horrible, horrible controls, some of them die. But I am not without compassion, so I revive them. That's when things go wrong.

I have done some testing, and dwellers seem to randomly choose one of three things to do after dying and being resurrected during an incident, after the incident is over. They either a) decide that being dead wasn't break enough and go idle (coffee break), b)return to their properly assigned work area (like all good dwellers should) or c) begin working in the room where they met their unfortunate demise.

No problem, right? Just wait till the incident is over, THEN revive them, right? No dice. They then either begin working in the room they woke up in, or go for coffee.

So my question. How do I predict what my dwellers will do after reviving? More importantly, how do I, if possible, force them to return to their regularly scheduled duties? (Removing rooms is not an option)

Answer (score 1):

The REAL answer is to actually setup your unused rooms to be immune to infestation spread.

Separate your rooms so the infestation does not spread, and it'll end in about 10 seconds all by itself without your intervention.  To do that, you place the rooms without it touching other rooms above, below, or beside them.

The result is you will no longer worry about your dwellers dying because you don't need to risk them to deal with infestations.

EDIT: as for actually controlling your dweller's action when revived during combat, it gets very dicey because it is hard to test.

I assume when multiple dwellers fight, they have a separate memory of where they were working.  However, dying causes their slot to be "freed" up and survivors can get reassigned to their slot.

The reason why I say survivors can shuffle around is because I notice they do not always return to the exact spot in the room.  I also notice the shuffling of dwellers when the application loads a save from a fresh start.

Comment: +1 because Answer addresses not-asked-for but central part of question. -1 because Answer does not ask question at all (reviving may still be necessary).

Comment: lol, that's true.  I'll fix the answer to answer the question.

Comment: This does not even attempt to answer the question

Comment: @Dallium I beg to differ.  I'm in the exact situation and the OP's problem doesn't occur to me.

Comment: Note that rooms with more dirt around them are more likely to suffer mole attacks.

Answer (score 1):

Dallium, I agree with what Nelson said.  You can't reliably predict what the dweller will do.

The game is designed to send them on a coffee break from what i can tell after they are revived, unless there was a battle.  My guess in this case is how the game handles dwellers that have been revived, but without testing it in depth, it's impossible to give specifics.

What I do know is that when a dweller dies, like Nelson said, it basically unassigns the dweller from their room slot.  If you decide to revive the dweller after battle, they will most likely go on a coffee break (may not be 100%).  If you revive them during battle, the game automatically tries to send them back to work after battle, which is where the problem most likely is.  At this point, the game probably has to figure out where they need to go, and it's hard to say how it figures this out.

So shorter answer, if you revive them after the fighting is over, you have a better chance to predict what the dwellers will do, and an easier time sending them back to work before they run off.  Otherwise there isn't a reliable way to predict what they will do (unless you keep them alive).

Comment: My suspicion is that it might be related to their happiness level. I've noticed that the ones going on coffee break after an emergency seem to tend to be the ones with lower happiness levels. I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

What I have observed is:

- When an emergency happens, all orders that you give to dwellers during the emergency (moving weaker dwellers to other rooms to avoid them dying, send stronger dwellers to deal with it) are automatically cancelled when the emergency ends (they return to their previous room, to coffe break, etc. Even dwellers that you send to the wastes remain inside).
- Resurrecting a dweller that was assigned to a room amounts to:

  - first resurrect,
  - then the dweller receives an order that assigns him/her to that room.
- So, if you resurrect the dweller when the emergency is still going on, when the emergency ends the room assignation order will be automatically cancelled, and the dweller will remain "in coffee break". If you want the dweller to stay in the room, you have to wait until the emergency ends to resurrect him/her.

Comment: Simply wrong. The problem remains even if you wait everytime until break is over.